# SVG scale animation also cause transformX and transformY to animate(anime.js)

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I have the following svg :-

```js
anime({
    targets: '#el-shape',
    scale: [0, 1],
    easing: 'easeInOutSine',
    duration: 1000,
    loop: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<svg
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
width="156.3371mm"
height="149.50702mm"
viewBox="0 0 156.3371 149.50702"
version="1.1"
id="svg8"
inkscape:version="0.92.2 5c3e80d, 2017-08-06"
sodipodi:docname="circle-check-mark-celebration-v2.svg">
<defs
  id="defs2" />
<sodipodi:namedview
  id="base"
  pagecolor="#ffffff"
  bordercolor="#666666"
  borderopacity="1.0"
  inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
  inkscape:pageshadow="2"
  inkscape:zoom="0.49497475"
  inkscape:cx="103.78147"
  inkscape:cy="280.57194"
  inkscape:document-units="mm"
  inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
  showgrid="false"
  inkscape:window-width="1440"
  inkscape:window-height="801"
  inkscape:window-x="0"
  inkscape:window-y="1"
  inkscape:window-maximized="1"
  fit-margin-top="0"
  fit-margin-left="0"
  fit-margin-right="0"
  fit-margin-bottom="0" />
<metadata
  id="metadata5">
 <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work
      rdf:about="">
     <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
     <dc:type
        rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
     <dc:title></dc:title>
   </cc:Work>
 </rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
<g
  inkscape:label="Layer 1"
  inkscape:groupmode="layer"
  id="layer1"
  transform="translate(-26.213772,-56.496415)">
 <path
    sodipodi:type="star"
    style="opacity:0.778;fill:red;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#80ff80;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
    id="el-shape"
    sodipodi:sides="3"
    sodipodi:cx="129.26785"
    sodipodi:cy="160.17261"
    sodipodi:r1="8.2896643"
    sodipodi:r2="4.1448326"
    sodipodi:arg1="0.42285393"
    sodipodi:arg2="1.4700515"
    inkscape:flatsided="false"
    inkscape:rounded="0"
    inkscape:randomized="0"
    d="m 136.82738,163.57439 -7.14266,0.72203 -7.14266,0.72203 2.94603,-6.54674 2.94603,-6.54673 4.19663,5.8247 z"
    inkscape:transform-center-x="-0.20729642"
    inkscape:transform-center-y="-0.91528581" />
</g>
</svg>
```

I am using anime.js to do a scale animation but the svg seems to be also moving on both the x and y axis , i would not like this to happen. How can i stop this moving on the x and y axis and only keep the scale animation ?

**Edit** :-

1. I can't center the triangle as there are other elements on the canvas.
2. Have removed the `matrix` on the svg element and also `trasformOrigin` in the JS code but the issue still persists

Comment: Copying your `svg` and previewing it, it seems like [your red triangle is not in the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJyT8.png). So, probably the `transformOrigin` is working as intended, just that your object is not in the center of the svg file.

Comment: @cSharp the svg object needs to be in that position as there are other svg objects , so i can't center it or even shirk the svg to be the size of the path object.

Comment: If the triangle has to be in that position with respect to the entire svg, and you have to center it to that triangle, I'm afraid you'll just have to figure out relatively what's the position (in percentages).

Comment: @cSharp thank you for the insight ! interesting point :)

Comment: Something to keep in mind, you have transformOrigin in your animation, so you're animating it from <whatever it was before> to 50%. Since you're also setting the transform attribute of your object, you'll also be animating between the transform produced by `transform: matrix(0.49727775,0,0,0.53811979,68.786166,70.171138)` and the transform you declared: `transform: scale(1)`. It's a little confusing because in anime.js terms they're different, they look different, they're set different, but ultimately they all interact with the same underlying transform property and will override each other.

Comment: @Different55 thanks interesting point. though if i remove `transform: matrix(0.49727775,0,0,0.53811979,68.786166,70.171138)` and also `transformOrigin` from the JS code , the effect shows no change. transform X and Y are still animated

Comment: Yeah, my bad, that won't fix the problem or else I would have posted as an answer. The transform origin is right to set, but it needs to be set elsewhere or else it's being animated. Even though you set it to 50% with no other value, any properties you're setting there will be animated, with 50% being the end keyframe with an implicit start keyframe of the initial, incorrect value. I guess you could set it to [50%, 50%] to make it explicit but that seems a bit hacky.

Comment: @Different55 true, i'am hoping to find a non hacky solution, else i'd be really bummed out. Thanks for all the insights though :D cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `transform-box: fill-box;` to `#el-shape`'s CSS.

[`transform-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box)  defines the layout box to which the `transform` and `transform-origin` properties relate. Initially, it is set to `view-box`, which sets it to the nearest SVG viewport.

> With view-box, the nearest SVG viewport is used as the reference box. Suppose a viewBox attribute is specified for the SVG viewport creating element. In that case, the reference box is positioned at the origin of the coordinate system established by the viewBox attribute, and the dimension of the reference box is set to the width and height values of the viewBox attribute.

When you set it to `fill-box`, The object bounding box is used as the reference box.

and now you can see it is working (you might need to scroll down a bit):

```js
anime({
    targets: '#el-shape',
    scale: [0, 1],
    easing: 'easeInOutSine',
    duration: 1000,
    loop: true
});
```

```css
#el-shape {
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" width="156.3371mm" height="149.50702mm" viewBox="0 0 156.3371 149.50702" version="1.1" id="svg8" inkscape:version="0.92.2 5c3e80d, 2017-08-06" sodipodi:docname="circle-check-mark-celebration-v2.svg">
  <defs id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview id="base" pagecolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1.0" inkscape:pageopacity="0.0" inkscape:pageshadow="2" inkscape:zoom="0.49497475" inkscape:cx="103.78147" inkscape:cy="280.57194" inkscape:document-units="mm" inkscape:current-layer="layer1" showgrid="false" inkscape:window-width="1440" inkscape:window-height="801" inkscape:window-x="0" inkscape:window-y="1" inkscape:window-maximized="1" fit-margin-top="0" fit-margin-left="0" fit-margin-right="0" fit-margin-bottom="0" />
  <metadata id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g inkscape:label="Layer 1" inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="layer1" transform="translate(-26.213772,-56.496415)">
    <path sodipodi:type="star" style="opacity:0.778;fill:red;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#80ff80;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1; transform-origin: center;" id="el-shape" sodipodi:sides="3" sodipodi:cx="129.26785" sodipodi:cy="160.17261" sodipodi:r1="8.2896643" sodipodi:r2="4.1448326" sodipodi:arg1="0.42285393" sodipodi:arg2="1.4700515" inkscape:flatsided="false" inkscape:rounded="0" inkscape:randomized="0" d="m 136.82738,163.57439 -7.14266,0.72203 -7.14266,0.72203 2.94603,-6.54674 2.94603,-6.54673 4.19663,5.8247 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```